# If a finitely generated semi-direct product $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on a non finitely generated group, can there be fixed points?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, semidirect-product, infinite-groups

Suppose that we have a group $G = K\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$, where $G$ is finitely generated, but $K$ is not finitely generated, and let $\phi(1)$ be the automorphism of $K$ corresponds to $1_\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Z}$, which defines the semi-direct product. Is it possible for $\phi(1)$ to have a fixed point that is not the identity in $K$?

I got this question when I was reading about the Lamplighter group, $L_2= \mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$, in this case $\phi(1)$ "shifts" every element in $\bigoplus_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2$ to the right by $1$. Then I was wondering if $G = K\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ has the above properties, is it true that $\phi(1)$ can't have fixed points in general?

I was thinking that if we write out the generating set of  $K=\langle k_1,\ldots,k_n \rangle $, where none of $k_i$ is the identity. It seems to me that $\phi(1)$ can't fix any of $k_i$.

Any help/counterexample would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=\bigoplus_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2$,

let $f:T\to T$ shift every element one step in the way you described,

and for the semi-direct product $G=(T\oplus\mathbb{Z})\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$,

let $\phi(1)(x,n)=(f(x),n)$.

Then $G$ is finitely generated, but $\phi(1)$ has a countably infinite number of fixed points.

$\\$

To see a different example, **in which the fixed points of $\phi(1)$ are not even a finitely generated group**, you can head over to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418977/if-k-rtimes-mathbbz-is-a-finitely-generated-group-but-k-isnt-must-the-f.

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering if you know whether this group is residually finite? (We know that the lamplighter group is a residually finite group)

Comment: @ghc1997 $L_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is residually finite

Comment: Really sorry, I meant to ask if you know whether the semidirect product $G=K\rtimes\mathbb{Z} = (L_2\oplus \mathbb{Z})\rtimes \mathbb{Z} $ is residually finite? (We know that the semidirect product $L_2= \bigoplus_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ is residually finite.)

Comment: @ghc1997 to avoid confusion about whether or not $L_2$ is just some elements of $\bigoplus_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2$ or also includes the action of shifting, I'll rephrase the answer. Also, a much stronger example than the one I gave in my answer is now on MathOverflow.