# If $K\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ is a finitely generated group but $K$ isn't, must the fixed points of $1_\mathbb{Z}$ be a finitely generated group?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, semidirect-product, infinite-groups

I recently answered the following question:

[If a finitely generated semi-direct product $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on a non finitely generated group, can there be fixed points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412471/if-a-finitely-generated-semi-direct-product-mathbbz-acting-on-a-non-finitel)

I have a related question:

Is there an example of a group $G=K\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, such that

- $G$ is finitely generated but $K$ is not finitely generated
- the fixed points of $\phi(1)$, which is the automorphism on $K$ corresponding to $1_\mathbb{Z}$, are not a finitely generated group?

I suspect there is an example, but I don't have enough experience with these sorts of groups to come up with one right away.

**EDIT**: I've also asked this on Math Overflow, for which [this is the link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418977/if-k-rtimes-z-is-a-finitely-generated-group-but-k-isnt-must-the-fixed-poin).

**FURTHER EDIT**: The question on Math Overflow has been answered positively.